The Norm of A Particular Family of Infinite Nonnegative Matrices
Let $H$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space. Let $E=(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis of $H.$ If for all $m,k\in\mathbb{N},$ $\langle ae_m,e_k\rangle\geq 0,$ $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\langle ae_m,e_j\rangle\leq 1,$ and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\langle ae_j,e_k\rangle\leq 1,$ does someone have a proof that $\|a\|\leq 1?$ I was able to prove this in the case $H$ finite dimensional, and it seems very clear to me that it must hold in this case, but I can't figure out a formal proof.

Lemma: If $(k_i), (t_i)$ are sequences of nonnegative numbers with $\sum_i k_i \leq 1$, then $(\sum_i k_it_i)^2 \leq \sum_i k_it_i^2$.
Proof: This is obvious when $\sum_i k_i = 0$. Otherwise, we have, by Jensen’s inequality,
$$\begin{split}
(\sum_i k_it_i)^2 &= (\sum_i k_i)^2(\frac{\sum_i k_it_i}{\sum_i k_i})^2\\
&\leq (\sum_i k_i)^2\frac{\sum_i k_it_i^2}{\sum_i k_i}\\
&= (\sum_i k_i)(\sum_i k_it_i^2)\\
&\leq \sum_i k_it_i^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \square
\end{split}$$
Now, let $h \in H$. We can write $h = \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$ for some $(\alpha_i) \in \ell^2$. Then,
$$\begin{split}
\|ah\|^2 &= \sum_i |\sum_j a_{ij}\alpha_j|^2\\
&\leq \sum_i (\sum_j a_{ij}|\alpha_j|)^2\\
&\leq \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}|\alpha_j|^2 \text{, as, for each fixed }i\text{, }\sum_j a_{ij} \leq 1\\
&= \sum_j (\sum_i a_{ij})|\alpha_j|^2\\
&\leq \sum_j |\alpha_j|^2 \text{, as, for each fixed }j\text{, }\sum_i a_{ij} \leq 1\\
&= \|h\|^2
\end{split}$$
Thus, $\|a\| \leq 1$.

I’m amazing how you always have an answer. Did you find this one or come up with it?

@MilesGould I came up with it. I would have cited the original source if I had found it somewhere.
